Smallest distance 9 self dual code CSS code
Very similar to a previous question at Smallest distance 9 self-dual CSS code? .
I'm wondering whats the smallest distance 9 self dual CSS code. There is a 23 qubit distance 7 Golay code and a 47 qubit distance 11 Code but is there a distance 9 code in between these two qubit counts?

What's different between this question and the one you linked? Why are you re-asking it instead of upvoting the other one?

The other question asks for any code with less than 49 qubits and has been answered with the distance 11, 47 qubit code. I'm interested specifically in the optimal distance 9 code.

@mathNoob the search I did is not exhaustive, so there could be such a code. The other question asked for a d=9 code with n<49. A d=11 code can be seen as a d=9 (or d=10) code...but I think you want one with d exactly 9. The search only considered the best known codes in GAP/GUAVA. There are many others ; maybe one that has d=9 exactly...it's probably quite a bit of work though to find it
